# How to add strings from a name list file to another file?

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

I have a fasta file (seq.fa) which is a standard file format for genetic info, like so:

```
>TR1|c0_g1_i1
GTCGAGCATGGTCTTGGTCATCTTCCTTTCAAAGAA
>TR6|c0_g1_i1
GTGGAATATCGCCAGTGACCATCACTGATTAACCTG
```

I also have a file with names matching the headers (">TR..." names):

```
TR1|c0_g1_i1    scaf0432344_50037.734_wgs
TR6|c0_g1_i1    scaf0159424_10142.072_wgs
```

I need to make the "scaf0..." identifiers the first thing coming after the ">" file in the seq.fa.

I want to keep the "TR..." identifiers which are unique to each of my sequences, like so:

```
>scaf0432344_50037.734_wgs|TR1|c0_g1_i1
GTCGAGCATGGTCTTGGTCATCTTCCTTTCAAAGAA
>scaf0159424_10142.072_wgs|TR6|c0_g1_i1
GTGGAATATCGCCAGTGACCATCACTGATTAACCTG
```

The names file is in the same order as the sequences file!

Haven't tried anything since I'm not trained and have no idea what I'm doing :/

Comment: Is the first blockquote the contents of a single file? Do you want to /replace/ the TR... thing by the scaf0...? Are the TR... lines unique in the first file? Are they in the same order in both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
  a[">"$1]=$2;next
}
$1 in a{
  sub(/>/,">"a[$1]"|",$1)
}1' file2 seq.fa
```

Get the scaf value from file2 and save it in an array `a` with index `">"$1`.

If `$1` of seq.fa is an index in array `a` substitute the `$1` to include the scaf value `a[$1]` after `>`.

Then print all lines in `seq.fa`

Comment: can you please explain your answer. It will take ages for me to understand this by myself.

Answer (score 1):

As variant

```
join <(paste - - <sqa.fa | cut -c2-) name -o 2.2,1.1,1.2 |
sed 's/^/>/;s/\s/|/;s/\s/\n/'
```